# Yeoman / AngularJS not loading CSS in development server

Tags: yeoman

I'm using the AngularJS Yeoman generator (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) and Express for the server. When running `grunt server`, it starts up my app fine and compiles .scss files into the .tmp folder in the root directory, but my pages don't automatically load that css. I have set up a link to the style/style.css stylesheet in my layout jade file.

I've also tried `grunt compass`, which works fine, but again, does not make it so my views actually load the css file in .tmp. I have the default compass setup in grunt.

Comment: this sounds stupid, but if you have one css file named 'main.sass' or 'main.scss' it will compile in both grunt server and grunt build. A stupid hack until there's better documentation around the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with live-reloading that has been addressed in newer releases. Update your generators through `yo` or by running `npm update -g generator-angular`. If you want to upgrade an existing project, you can run `yo angular` in the same directory and choose the diff option to see the changes you have to make.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and updating the generator does not solve the problem. Which did solve the problem for me was regenerating the app using different options. When answering "Y" to bootstrap it worked

Answer (score 0):

As for May 22, 2015 ... the yeoman generator-angular does not work correctly unless you select Yes when asked if you'd like to include the Twitter Bootstrap.  Perhaps subsequent releases will fix this.

On a good note, there are much less problems with the generator-angular than with generator-angular-ui-router (which is a disaster)